# Is it possible to change handling order of TableView and SearchBar Delegates?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbardelegate

I have custom class, inherited from `UISearchBar` with dropdown tableview, and both delegates related to this class.

I've notice, that `UISearchBarDelegate` methods calls before `UITableViewDelegate`, but for my goals I need to change it. Is it possible anyhow to manage them, or combine?

For example, if user will tap outside of searchField, `didEndEditing` method will be triggered, and keyboard will hide, so I want to hide my `tableView` too (it presents search suggestion), but there is one case : when tapping to `tableView` row, it's triggered `didEndEditing` too, before the `didSelectRow`, which, in turn, will never be called, because `tableView` is hidden, and there is actually no cells.

If I will remove closeing tableview from didEndEditing, I could not close it, when user tap somewhere else.

So if it's possible to handle `tableView` methods first, it will help me a lot. Maybe, some generic protocol for them could be used..

```
       private func closeTableView() {
                var frame = self.tableView.frame
                frame.size.height = 0
                self.tableView.frame = frame
                self.tableView.sizeToFit()
            }
    ...
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            print("didSelectRowAt")
...        
            self.closeTableView() 
       
        }
    
    extension CustomSearchBar: UISearchBarDelegate {
    
        ...
    
        func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
          print("searchBarTextDidEndEditing")            
          self.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
          self.closeTableView()
        }
    }
```

and when tap on the table row, in console is only:

```
    searchBarTextDidEndEditing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change order of delegate calls. But you can wait a little bit before actually closing your table view:

```
private var closeTableViewNeeded = false

private func setNeedsCloseTableView() {
    guard !closeTableViewNeeded else { return }
    closeTableViewNeeded = true
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
        closeTableViewNeeded = false
        closeTableView()
    }
}
```

And call `setNeedsCloseTableView()` instead of `closeTableView`

Usually waiting next runloop cycle with `DispatchQueue.main.async` is enough. I'm not sure it that'll be the case here because of keyboard and table view layout, so if this won't work add `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1)` instead of `DispatchQueue.main.async`

Comment: great, thank you! DispatchQueue.main.async works perfect! you save me from detecting touch location, etc, thank you for your time!